# Oracle - updating a sorted table

Tags: sql, oracle

I found an old table without a primary key, and in order to add one, I have to add a new column and fill it with sequence values. I have another column which contains the time of when the record was created, so I want to insert the sequence values to the table sorted by the column with the time.

I'm not sure how to do it. I tried using PL\SQL - I created a cursor for a query that returns the table with an ORDER BY, and then update for each record the cursor returns but it didn't work.

Is there a smart working way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The method you've described should have worked so what "didn't work"? Can you post the code? Also the "order" rows are entered into a table bear no relation to the order they come out in and little to their place on the disk. You will have to use an order by if you want other than the max or min pk out (the only reason I can think of for what you're doing) so is there any point to this at all?

Comment: I wrote the code at work and I won't be there until Sunday. It was pretty simple - 
LOOP
 FETCH c INTO rec
 UPDATE table SET new_col = seq.nextval WHERE time = rec.time
END LOOP

What I got was some really weird values in that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is just to use a correlated subquery, with the wrinkle of a nested subquery to generate the row number. Setting up some sample data:

```
create table t42 (datefield date);
insert into t42 (datefield) values (sysdate - 7);
insert into t42 (datefield) values (sysdate + 6);
insert into t42 (datefield) values (sysdate - 5);
insert into t42 (datefield) values (sysdate + 4);
insert into t42 (datefield) values (sysdate - 3);
insert into t42 (datefield) values (sysdate + 2);

select * from t42;

DATEFIELD
---------
12-JUL-12
25-JUL-12
14-JUL-12
23-JUL-12
16-JUL-12
21-JUL-12
```

Then adding and populating the new column:

```
alter table t42 add (id number);

update t42 t1 set t1.id = (
    select rn from (
        select rowid, row_number() over (order by datefield) as rn
        from t42
    ) t2
    where t2.rowid = t1.rowid
);

select * from t42 order by id;

DATEFIELD         ID
--------- ----------
12-JUL-12          1
14-JUL-12          2
16-JUL-12          3
21-JUL-12          4
23-JUL-12          5
25-JUL-12          6
```

Since this is a synthetic key, making it match the order of another column seems a bit pointless, but I guess doesn't do any harm.

---

To complete the task:

```
alter table t42 modify id not null;

alter table t42 add constraint t42_pk primary key (id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't make the timestamp column a primary key since it has duplicate values (it's a log table and there are records that have been inserted at the same second).

Comment: @Bennyz - sure, I understand you can't use the `date` field as a PK, I just meant giving the new PK order any significance is odd. If new values will be from a sequnce, for example, the order of those won't be guaranteed (esp. in RAC).

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, create new field and allow null values.
- Then, update field from other table or query. Best approach is to use [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) statement.

Here a sample from documentation:

```
MERGE INTO bonuses D
   USING (SELECT employee_id, salary, department_id FROM employees
   WHERE department_id = 80) S
   ON (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01
     DELETE WHERE (S.salary > 8000)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.employee_id, D.bonus)
     VALUES (S.employee_id, S.salary*.01)
     WHERE (S.salary <= 8000);
```

- Finally, set as [non null this new field](http://dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_modify_column_syntax_example.htm) and promote it to primary key.

Here sample sentences:

```
ALTER TABLE 
   customer 
MODIFY 
   ( 
   your_new_field varchar2(100) not null
   )
;
ALTER TABLE 
   customer 
ADD CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (your_new_field)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create a new table, with new column an all other columns:

```
create table newt (
    newtID int primary key not null,
    . . .
)
```

Then insert all the old data into it:

```
insert into newt
    select row_number() over (order by <CreatedAt>), t.*
    from t
```

(You can substitute all the columns in, instead of using "*".  Having the columns by name is the better practice.  This is shorter, plus, I don't know the column names.)

If you alter the table to add the column, then the column will appear at the end.  I find that quite awkward for the primary key.  If you do that, though, you can update it as:

```
with t as (select row_number() over (order by <CreatedAt>) as seqnum, t.*
           from t
          )
update t
    set newtID = seqnum
```